# C program's execution speed increases all of the sudden

Tags: c, performance, execution

I wrote a C program to convert temperature from Fahrenheit scale to Celsius scale. When I ran my program and I noticed that the execution speed drastically increased when  the loop was about to end (which should not as per my code). I have tried to initialize the loop with different values as well as changed the ending of the loop but still the behavior remains the same.

I am attaching an image and posting a link of the execution speed's video.

I have provided the video so you can see that when the loop crosses 399999, the execution speed increases and in the image you can see some details/version of the compiler.

Please tell me why is this happening.
Thanks.

[Link to the video of execution speed](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1XKfya6gG3lh46-q0-EcqetlVfaiq-L4A/view?usp=sharing)

[Link to the image of my ide](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uoMkZ.jpg)

My Code :-

```
// Program to convert temperature from 
// fahrenheit scale to celsius scale. 

#include <stdio.h>
main()
{
    float faren, celsius;
    for(faren=200000; faren<=900000; faren = faren+20)
    {
        celsius = (5.0/9.0)*(faren-32);
        printf("%.f\t%3.5f\n",faren, celsius);
    }
}
```

Comment: What shall we expect in the video, could you write this in the question? How is a screenshot of the IDE related to the question, could you add all necessary information in the question? It might be helpful to enter space characters to create space in the code listing.

Comment: Probably some mystery in the internals of `printf` or your console. Try using `perf record` on the portion below the threshold and above to see if your time gets spent in different places.

Comment: Can you post the assembly of the code in question? Also, are you measuring `printf` execution time, too? Does `printf` execution time increases after 3999999 executions and celsuis calculation execution time stays the same?

Comment: What do you mean with "when the loop was about to end (which should not as per my code)"? Why shouldn't the loop end?

Comment: Divide and rule! Repeat the measurement with only the calculation and only the `printf`.

Comment: Caching and code optimization... It might(might bcoz I didnt test it myself) be the trick of the gcc compiler and the flags. To make it slower than what you are currently experiencing, try using gcc -O0  to disable any optimizations on your code. Also make the variables as volatile to just make sure the values doesnt get cached.

Comment: Your code's execution time is almost entirely down to the performance and behaviour of `printf()`, and that in turn is dominated by your OS's console output performance and process scheduling behaviour.  Remove the `printf()` and it will take a few tens of microseconds (50-60 in my test at https://www.onlinegdb.com/).  Rather then relying on video perception, you would do better to add timing to the code itself, and present the results - off-site resources critical to your explanation does not make a good SO question.

Comment: @Clifford: It is not a matter of video perception; using a video editor to examine the specific times where various output appears shows a large speed-up at the 4000000 mark. And the behavior is not caused by `printf`; the CPU time to format this output is negligible. The speed change is undoubtedly experienced in the software that renders the console window display, although it may be due to something in that software or due to effects from system activity such as swapping.

Comment: @EricPostpischil you have completely misunderstood my comment.  I was referring to the visual display and rendering performance of the PC.  The calculation and display content generation takes negligible time, the rendering of glyphs in a video display is entirely non deterministic.

Comment: I am voting to close this as too broad because it cannot be answered without more information and investigation, and, even then, the answer will not be generally useful. It is certain the behavior is not due to anything internal to the program in the question, and it is very likely the behavior is due to either the console window software and rendering or to general system behavior.

Answer (score 2):

This is only your operating system allocating more CPU time for this process.

In basic terms and by basic I mean really basic, Your OS (Windows in this case) sets a timer with a given duration, after the duration finishes it will change the current process and switch to the next one. This is why you feel like your computer is doing several things  together and you can listen to music and also browse the web. (This duration is pretty small and it depends on the operating system)

Every time the operating system sees that a process has not finished in that given duration, it will increase the duration for that process ONLY so that the next time it is that process's turn it will have more time to finish.

Now when the OS sees that your process (Program that is running) has not finished after the first duration, next time it will increase that duration for your process making the CPU spend more time on your process.

This will cause your program (Which does not have any constraints for CPU ticks because it is a simple C/C++ program) to speed up after a while.

Comment: Good answer. There are tons of other compiler optimizations and CPU runtime optimizations like branch predictions going on but at some point we have to remember this isn't running on a real-time operating system with fixed timeslices for calculations and we shouldn't expect it to behave like that.

Comment: Nice answer. Actually from this week i started learning C, and your answer didn't had advanced terms, which in turn, cleared by doubt for my code's behavior.

Comment: Can you give any source for your statement that the operating system repeatedly increases the quantum allocated for a CPU-bound process?

Comment: Additionally, it would not be the OP’s C program that is speeding up here; it is a simple program that could easily produce all of its results in little time. The burden on the system here would be on rendering the window, which is handled by other processes. And they are not processes that “finish”; they respond to requests of various sorts, update their windows and do other tasks, and then wait for more. I would expect them to be I/O-bound (waiting for devices) in this case, so giving them more CPU time would not speed them up.

Comment: On top of that, unless there is significant other work going in the system, increasing the quantum for one process will not give it significantly more time. When a system is generally idle, any new CPU-bound process will get most of the CPU. It might get it for one unit, then the system checks, but, since the system is mostly idle, there is usually nothing else ready to run, so the system gives it two units, then four, then eight. But if it were just one, then one, then one, it would still get most of the CPU time, since nothing else is competing for it.

Comment: @EricPostpischil The OS,  does not increase the quantum for any processes; the OS just puts them in a different queue that has a different round robin quantum. Like I said I was explaining in very basic and simple terms.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Actually rendering the window was something that I had not considered, What you are saying is true, however that does not explain why the program speeds up.

Comment: @EricPostpischil The system is never idle because the operating system is running and also no desktop computer is idle either because of the fact that people have many background processes running.

Comment: @TheGreatA: No, the operating system is not running all the time. When the kernel has no immediate work to do, it allows the processor(s) to go into sleep or low-power modes. My Mac system currently shows 90% idle even as I am typing this, and around 98-99% when I am not.

Comment: Schemes used for adjusting process priorities and implementing round-robin queues within priorities operate on millisecond time scales. The effect shown in the video occurs after 14 seconds. More likely explanations are either a deliberate effect by the terminal window software (when a program within the terminal is emitting large amounts of output, the terminal software might decide to consolidate updates instead of drawing every one) or some system activity such as swapping out other processes to provide more memory to the active software.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I believe that Idle time you are talking about is basically showing how many User processes exist and will not consider the kernel processes and or background processes. However I believe your explanations to be more accurate.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Wouldn't those millisecond differences on the quantum cause visible changes?

Comment: Also remember that OP's program doesn't allocate more space inside the memory as time goes on because there is no memory allocations statement inside the loop.

Comment: The idle time is idle, not kernel. Kernel time is accounted for separately. For example, my system currently shows 1.68% user, 2.89% system, and 95.41% idle.

Comment: There are memory allocations caused by the user’s program—outside of the program itself. The software for the console window may be keeping all the text that has been printed, it its buffer for scrolling back.

Comment: The point about millisecond scale is that performance changes due to reprioritization of a process would be visible in milliseconds, not 14 seconds later. Also, schemes to balance processes’ use of CPU time generally penalize, not reward, a process for using too much CPU time, in order to avoid one process monopolizing the CPU and crowding others out.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Why would memory swapping increase the speed of the program?

Comment: @TheGreatA: Prior to the OP starting the program, other memory may have been in use because other processes had been running (the compiler, the IDE, background network activity, other background system activities, whatever applications the OP ran before, et cetera). As the OP’s program ran and the console program requested memory, the system may have swapped out the dirty memory of other processes or discarded the non-dirty memory (such as read-only pages from executable files), making more room for the console terminal software.

Comment: This answer seems to explain an old hack I came up with in JavaScript to force the event loop to run faster. If you schedule more [`setTimeout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout) than can be processed by the program on time, it seems to allow asynchronously scheduled callbacks to be executed more quickly the more backlog pressure there is on the event loop.